# extend IE with .net (VB or C#)

Tags: .net, internet-explorer, extend, add-on

I want to write IE extension in .Net (VB/C#)

I already have experience writing firefox addons.

All I want to do is, manipulate the DOM before showing it to the user. Like remove some stuff, highlight words, etc...

Is it possible to do it using .Net? Or is the only way C++/ATL and those things?

I tried searching, but the only useful search results that came close were an unanswered forum question and a website that asks me to buy their $149 product to extend using .net

*P.S. Please no **"extending FF is so easy, why u extending IE? IE sucks, FF so cool"** kind of comments.*

Answer (score 2):

Yes it can be done by writing a Browser Helper Object that uses COM Interop. The article [*Build a Managed BHO and Plug into the Browser*](https://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_general/comcom/article.php/c19613/Build-a-Managed-BHO-and-Plug-into-the-Browser.htm) has a very good example of how to do this.

Additionally Microsoft themselves have published some extensive documentation on how to write [browser extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa753587(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN). However the mention that writing extensions in a managed language has some negative drawbacks:

> **Important**  Because extensions run in-process with the browser process, they should not be written using managed code.

That advice is a little old, and the issue may not be as great as it once was. There are also some reference links on that page which help explain why:

- [*The Old New Thing: Do not write in-process shell extensions in managed code*](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/2006/12/18)
- [*Now that version 4 of the .NET Framework supports in-process side-by-side runtimes, is it now okay to write shell extensions in managed code?*](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/2013/02/22)
- [*In-Process Side-by-Side*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/december/clr-inside-out-in-process-side-by-side)
- [*Add-on Performance Part 3: Optimizing Add-on Startup Performance*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ie/add-on-performance-part-3-optimizing-add-on-startup-performance)

Comment: @kristian That was a very old answer... in any case I've fixed it up. You should also have looked at the [answer above](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1960667/109702), it needs some attention. I would suggest that you could edit it rather than voting to delete it in the review queue, some of these answers link to some excellent information.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done. Have a look at [this post on the IE8 blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2005/09/06/461675.aspx) that gives some details and links to resources on how to extend IE using C# or other .NET languages.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Greasemonkey for IE](http://www.gm4ie.com/) to manipulate the DOM. You can use .NET to generate this javascript by serving it and entering the url in the ScriptURL attribute.

Comment: Also, *just extend the dom* is a starting point. It may grow into a full addon. So Greasemonkey wouldn't be enough right? Anyway, Thanks for the link :)

Comment: Yes, this would just manipulate the DOM and the user would have to have the Greasemonkey for IE extension installed.